# What is the most efficient way of accessing a property from an array of objects in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, performance

I have been watching some CBT Nuggets on PowerShell recently and in one of them the instructor says that utilizing `ForEach-Object` should be a last resort with using available `cmdlets` and `WMI Methods` first.  So, my question is what would be the most efficient way to get a property from multiple objects of the same type?  For example:

would this:

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
```

be more efficient than this:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}
```

and how do these function differently from each other?

Comment: I think the general rule is that if the cmdlet allows you to filter, you should use it.  This avoids putting a bunch of stuff you don't need in the pipeline.  When typing the command, push any filtering as far to the "left" as you can (i.e. prefer cmdlet built-in filtering to ForEach-Object or Select-Object)

Comment: To improve the efficiency of a process, you should look to the `whole solution` as **the performance of a complete (PowerShell) solution is supposed to be better than the sum of its parts**, see also: [Fastest Way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#This is compatible with PowerShell 3 and later only
    (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name

#This is the more compatible method
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#This technically works, but is inefficient.  Might be useful if you need to work with the other properties
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}

#This breaks the pipeline, but could be slightly faster than Foreach-Object
    foreach($computer in (Get-ADComputer -Filter *) )
    {
        $computer.name
    }
```

I generally stick to Select-Object -ExpandProperty to ensure compatibility.

Cheers!